# Silverstripe 3: Add a custom block to HTMLEditorField

Tags: silverstripe

I want to add the option to create a 'div' in the html editor field.

How do I add an option to the format dropdown list that will create a div with a specific class?

I have added a style successfully to the styles dropdown with this code in editor.css

```css
.responsive-table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I am using silverstripe 3 and want to be able to add my own options to the format dropdown to create various elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3 we can edit style dropdown items in our `HTMLEditorField` by adding the following to our `mysite/_config.php`:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('style_formats', [
    [
        'title' => 'Responsive table',
        'attributes' => ['class' => 'responsive-table'],
        'selector' => 'div',
    ],
]);
```

The above code will make the `HTMLEditorField` style dropdown have one item in it, a `Responsive table` option that can be applied to `div` elements. If we prefer this to be applied to `table` elements we can change this in the `selector` option.

Here is a handy module that shows examples of how we can make changes to the `HTMLEditorField` in SilverStripe 3:
https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy/blob/master/_config.php

Comment: I have got this to work and create a div. However, I also had some custom styles which I was editing in editor.css and including using `HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('content_css', project() . '/css/editor.css');` 
Is it possible to have this still work without having to code the old styles into config.php as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's either one or the other. Either you can set all the options of the style dropdown through the above `setOption` `style_formats` method or through the `setOption` `content_css` method linking off to the classes in an `editor.css` file.